# ActiveAdmin: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::UsersController#show when editing current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

When I am logged in as an admin on my rails app, I go to the admin page and then to the `Users` column in activeadmin (Which includes admin users). When I click `edit` for the admin-user that is currently logged in, I edit the fields, and then when I click `Update User` I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::UsersController#update
Couldn't find User with id=5 [WHERE ('t'='f')]
```

This only happens when I do the above procedure for the `current_user` and not for any other user.

This my `admin/users.rb` file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :last_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end

  filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Admin Details" do
      f.input :email
      f.input :initials
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

And Here is my `user.rb` model file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_associated_audits
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me ,:name, :initials
  has_many :entries
end
```

Comment: Because 't' will never be 'f'.

Comment: What version of Rails is this project? Have you tried removing has_associated_audits?

Answer (score 1):

[WHERE ('t'='f')] Condition can never be true !

Comment: @Ov3rc10ck3d true, but why is that even the DB Query?

Comment: obviously I didn't write that SQL query :).